# How can I display a floating values with corresponding index in a list?

Tags: python

Im new to python btw
This is the problem.

> Accept a list of float numbers as user input then display the values with their
> corresponding index.

Example, The user inputs 1.1, 2.2 on the list, When I try to print the floating inputs from the user its always shows like this:

```
1 1
2 .
3 1
4 2
5 .
6 2
```

but I want it to be

```
1 1.1
2 2.2
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have tried.

Comment: It sounds like you're not putting the numbers into a list. You're looping over the characters of the input instead of splitting it into numbers.

Comment: The corresponding index shall be like: 
`
0  1.1`&
`1 2.2
`

Answer (score 1):

assumed getting "1.1, 2.2, ..." as input, below script can be used.

```py
    inputs = input() # assumed getting "1.1, 2.2, ..."

    inputs = inputs.split(", ")

    for i, input in enumerate(inputs):
        print(i+1, input)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
inp = input()
for i in range(len(inp)):
    print(f'{i}\t{inp[i]}'
```

It will works as per your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    inputs = [1.1, 2.2]


    for i in range(len(inputs)):
        print(str(i+1) + "\t" + str(inputs[i]))
```

> output is:
> 1   1.1
> 2   2.2